# How to transform specific time entry into month in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a dataset with a column "Day" that has very specific time entries like the following. How can I transform these entries into month?

From

| Day |
| --- |
| 31MAY2019:00:00:00 |
| 29MAY2020:00:00:00 |
| 30APR2021:00:00:00 |

To

| Day |
| --- |
| May 2019 |
| May 2020 |
| Apr 2021 |

Comment: What do you mean by "transform"?  Do you just want to display the year and month for those values? Then use an appropriate format, like DTMONYY7.  Or do you want to make a new variable?  What type of value would you like in the variable? Character string? A different datetime value?  A date value?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the `datepart()` function to get extract the date from the datetime value.

```
data want;
format datetime datetime20. date monyy7.;
datetime = '31MAY2019:00:00:00'dt;
date = datepart(datetime);
run;
```

Keep in mind this doesn't add the space in between the month and year and is still a number format. If you want this as a character you can do the following:

```
data want;
format datetime datetime20.;
datetime = '31MAY2019:00:00:00'dt;
date = put(datepart(datetime),monname3.)||' '||put(datepart(datetime),year.);
run;
```

Comment: To expand further, to truly convert it to a month that can be used easily in queries, you would need to do: `intnx('month', datepart(datetime), 0, 'B')` then format it as `monyy7.`.  This way if they need to query for each month, they just choose the first of the month. e.g. `'01SEP2021'd` = Sep 2021, `'01OCT2021'd` = Oct 2021, etc.